# In Drools: How to cancel the rule fire when the match is judged useless?

Tags: drools

This case is :

1. get the match with BeforeMatchFiredEvent of DefaultAgendaEventListener
2. judge the match is useless
3. I want to canche the rule, how to do it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why don't you just fix your rule definition so it doesn't match?

Comment: I want to control it dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

You change your rule so that it doesn't trigger when the match is useless.

Simple example -- original rule like this:

```
rule "Shirt is blue"
when
  Shirt(color == "blue")
then
end
```

In this scenario, the match is "useless" when the shirt is also size XL. So we simply change the rule definition to not allow for XL shirts.

```
rule "Shirt is blue (but not XL)"
when
  Shirt(color == "blue", size != "XL")
then
end
```

Alternatively, you could use flags/markers and check for their presence. Here's a simple example where we make some sort of expensive call to figure stuff out ...

```
rule "Determine football jersey sale price"
when
  $tournamentWinner: String()
  $jersey : Jersey( price == null, team != $tournamentWinner )
then
  $jersey.setPrice(19.99)
end

rule "Determine tournament winner"
salience 1
when
  not(String())
  $service: TeamDataService()
then
  // assume this is an expensive call:
  String $tournamentWinner = $service.getTournamentWinner()

  // insert the results into working memory so the other 2 rules are now valid
  insert($tournamentWinner)
end

rule "Special price for tournament winner"
when
  $tournamentWinner: String()
  $jersey: Jersey( price == null, team == $tournamentWinner)
then
  $jersey.setPrice(25.00)
end
```

... or you can modify working memory directly to cause the rule no longer to be valid:

```
rule "Apply discount"
when
  $discount: Discount()
  $cart: Cart( total > 0 )
then
  $cart.apply($discount)
end

rule "Remove expired discounts"
salience 1
when
  $discount: Discount(expired == true)
then
  // Since the discount will no longer be in working memory, the other rule's match
  // will be cancelled
  retract($discount)
end
```

If you try to use listeners to modify the matches you're going to end up with a concurrent modification exception. Listeners listen; they don't modify.

If you need a rule not to match you need to write it so that it doesn't match.